# If a function integrates to zero against every function with zero mean, then it is constant

Tags: calculus, integration

Struggling with this calculus problem:

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$   be
a smooth function. Show that if
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)v(x)dx = 0 $$ 
for every smooth function $v : [0, 1] \to\mathbb R$ for which

$$ \int_{0}^{1}v(x)dx = 0 $$

then $f$ is constant. (Hint: integrate by parts.)

With by parts, I'm getting to $$  \left[f(x) \int v(x)dx\right] \bigg|_0^1  - \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int v(x)dx\,f(x)\right)$$ and don't know where to go. I'm not sure if I can make the integrals inside definite to make them zero by the definition. Can I use $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x) = f(1)-f(0) $$ Is that appropriate? It says the function is smooth. (continuous?)

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus? $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = F(1)-F(0)$$ where $F$ (not f) is an antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: Note that the left hand side of your integration by parts evaluates to zero because of the conditions on $v$.

Comment: With $  \left[f(x) \int v(x)dx\right] \bigg|_0^1  - \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int v(x)dx\,f(x)\right)$? I just get on the LHS $f(1)V(1) - f(0)V(0)$. How does this become zero by definition of v?  I know that means $V(1) = V(0)$ so $c(f(1)-f(0))$ with $c=V(0)=V(1)$

Answer (score 5):

Let $m = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$. Then we have 
$$\int_0^1 (f(x)-m)^2 dx =0$$

Indeed: 
$$\int_0^1 (f(x)-m)^2 dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \cdot (f(x) -m) dx - \int_0^1 m\cdot (f(x) -m) dx$$

Now $\int_0^1 (f(x)-m)dx = \int_0^1 f(x) - m \cdot 1 = 0$ and so the first term above is zero (by hypothesis) and the second also.

Therefore $f(x) \equiv m$.

Comment: nice answer - this is simpler than using integration by parts.

Comment: Why is it true that $$\int_0^1 (f(x)-m)^2 dx =0$$

Comment: @Kevin Carroll: The integral is a sum of the  other  integrals. The first of them is zero since for $v(x)$  you can take $f(x)-m$, smooth with zero integral.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks! It only works because $f$ is smooth.

Comment: @orangeskid Ok. I understand now. You just expanded the square to get the result. In the first one you made the $v(x) = f(x)-m$ and showed that when you integrate that you get zero, so the whole thing is zero. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that does not involve integration by parts directly.

Note that $\int_0^1 f(x) v(x) dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^x f'(t) dt dx = \int_0^1 f'(t) \int_t^1 v(x)dx dt$.

Let $\phi(t) = \int_t^1 v(x) dx$, we note that $\phi$ is smooth and $\phi(0) = \phi(1) = 0$ (under the assumption that $v$ has zero average). Furthermore, any smooth $\phi$ that matches at the end points corresponds to some zero average $v$ (specifically, $v= -\phi'$).

Hence we have $\int_0^1 f'(t) \phi(t)dt = 0$ for any smooth $\phi$ such that $\phi(0) = \phi(1)$. If $f'(t^*) > 0$ for some $t^*$, we can find a small interval containing $t^*$ such that $f'(t)>{1 \over 2} f'(t^*)$ on this interval. Then we can find a smooth $\phi$ such that the support of $\phi$ is contained in this interval, and $\int \phi = 1$. This would result in
$\int f' \phi \ge L{1 \over 2} f'(t^*) > 0$ (where $L$ is the length of the interval), a contradiction. Similarly if $f'(t^*) < 0$. Hence $f'(t) = 0$ everywhere, and so $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I follow your post, but how would one approach the by-parts method to show f is constant?

Comment: Well, the integration by parts you have shows that $\int f v = - \int f' \int v$. From there on, you can use the above approach.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^t v + \int_t^1 v = 0$.

Comment: I can only see it as far as $$\int_{0}^{1}fv = -\int_{0}^{1}[\int f' \int v] $$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}fv = 0$$...

Comment: Omit the integral before f'

Comment: Are you familiar with 'bump' functions?